# How to use 2 higher-order components at the same time? (in order to use injectIntl from react-intl)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I know that in order to use injectIntl from the react-intl library  I will need something like:

```
export default injectIntl(SectionNavbars)
```

However I am already using the withStyles higher order component, how can I combine both?

```
import React from 'react'
/* more stuff */
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl'

class SectionNavbars extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { intl } = this.props;
    return (

      <div className={classes.section}>
        <Header
          brand={ <img src={logo}/> }
          rightLinks={
              <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                <CustomDropdown
                        buttonText={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'products' })}
                        buttonProps={{
                          className: classes.navLink,
                        }}
                        dropdownList={[
                         /*stuff*/
                        ]}
                      />
              </ListItem>
          }
        />
      </div>
   );
  }
}

export default withStyles(navbarsStyle)(SectionNavbars);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine HOC like this `injectIntl(withStyles(navbarsStyle)(SectionNavbars))`

Or better

1. you can use `compose` from [recompose library](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/)
2. other helpers for functional programming like `flow` and `flowRight` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flow)

Also, I would recommend you to read recompose documentation it really helps to understand HOC and provides really useful stuff.

Comment: injectIntl(withStyles(navbarsStyle)(SectionNavbars)) is working fine, thanks! While I am at it may I ask why it would be better to use the recompose library?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. It's better organization of the code. It's easier to read and edit. In your case, there are only two functions but it may be much more. 2. Knowledge of recompose can save you a lot of time. Amoung other HOC I would especialy recommend you to take a closer look at `withStateHandlers()` , `withPropsOnChange()`. Having "Pure" component and all state and logic encapsulated into HOC organized with `compose` is a very good practice.